# How to access ubuntu server with apache open meeting from internet

Tags: xubuntu, tomcat, syslinux

I'm new and selflerner. I have configured a apache open meeting in ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu has been installed as VM guest using windows server 2016. Open meeting is running on ubuntu local host properly. Both guest and host has two separate public IPs, x.x.x.155, x.x.x.157. I can ping those from internet. All the firewalls and virus guards has been disabled. If I try x.x.x.155/localhost, from internet I only get a error. Host and guest can ping each other but host cant access guest localhost. What am I doing wrong. Is there any place or script to configure. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is Apache configured to listen on the public IP-address or only on localhost ?

Comment: I did not installed apache. I think open meeting is using tomcat

Comment: I know that tomcat is also from apache. Is apache there by default. If so, Is there a script to edit and where is it?.

Comment: I just saw `Apache open meeting" so I assumed Apache. But if you are using Tomcat to serve the question is the same; is Tomcat configured to listen on the public IP-address or only on localhost ? In general, if you want a service to be available from the public net, it must listen on the public ip-address.